# Having issue with CTFontRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sdk

Hi I need using a couple of fonts with `CTFontRef` for an iPad application , I need use this method because my font is not English . so I found this code from this [site](http://frankzblog.appspot.com/?p=8001)

but compiler gives me some error :

```
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("myfont"), 12,NULL);

NSMutableAttributedStringRef attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textView.text];
[attrString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName
                   value:(id)font
                   range: NSMakeRange(0, textView.text.length)];
```

[image]

I would be grateful if you help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is with the `NSMutableAttributedStringRef`. Use an `NSMutableAttributedString` instead:

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello World!!";
CTFontRef futura = CTFontCreateWithName( CFSTR("Futura"), 24.0, NULL);

NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] 
        initWithString:myString];

[attString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName
                  value:(id)futura
                  range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just see this. may be useful for you :

```
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("GujaratiSangamMN-Bold"),12.0f, NULL);
NSDictionary *attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       (id)font, kCTFontAttributeName,
                       nil];
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textView.text
                                                                 attributes:attrs];
```

Comment: thank you , how can I use attrString ? because its unusable , because the font did not change

Comment: the font of Textview.text should be changed ! that's it